# My code will not print the value of s for some reason?

Tags: python, list, function, class

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
    def i(self, d):
        self.v = self.v + d


s = [C(i) for i in range(1, 4)]
s1 = s[1]
s1.i(10)
print(s)
```

I run this code and get this :

```
[<__main__.C object at 0x000001F911306160>, <__main__.C object at 0x000001F911341220>, <__main__.C object at 0x000001F911341520>]
```

How can i make that decipherable so i can know what s is

Comment: Did you try: `print(''.join(s))`? Since an array is an object, it will just print the reference address. You need to ouput the values.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

usse `__repr__`

```
class C:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{}>".format(self.v)
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
    def i(self, d):
        self.v = self.v + d


s = [C(i) for i in range(1, 4)]
s1 = s[1]
s1.i(10)
print(s)
```

output

```
 [<1>, <12>, <3>]
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this however is it possible to use this code somewhere to get the desired result of [C(1), C(12), C(3)] : def __str__(self):
    return f"C({self.v})"

Comment: u can use it as u like

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
    def i(self, d):
        self.v = self.v + d
        return self.v

s = [C(i).i(10) for i in range(1, 4)]
print(s)
```

I corrected some little things, but the main thing is that you have to `return` you `self.v` in `i` in the `class`.

Comment: Hi thank you for this however i need the code to return [C(1), C(12), C(3)]. This is apparently the final result i need

Comment: I tried using this code def __str__(self):
    return f"C({self.v})"                                    But it does not return the intended final result

Comment: @pizzapizza I edited my answer please check again

Comment: I checked however it is not printing [C(1), C(12), C(3)].